# Create a view on an integer?

Tags: sql, function, view

I have a table named A. it has only one record with one field. It is an integer named number.
I want to create a view that have A.number records, each are one of the numbers less than A.number.

For example:

select A.number -----> 5

the view should show 5 records  0  1  2  3  4

P.S: This is a real problem that I simplified it a lot. The real problem is like dividing a budget in a fixed period to each day.

Comment: Is this homework, or a puzzle from somewhere?

Comment: None of them. A real problem. The main problem is more complicated. I just simplified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit like it might be homework, so I'm wary of providing the code outright.

I can give a pointer for how to solve the question, though. You use a recursive CTE where each iteration adds one to the previous iteration. Just be sure to set the MAXRECURSION option if you'll be checking numbers > 101. You can use a scalar sub query to key the view to the original table:

---

```
WITH numbers ( n ) AS (
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + n FROM numbers WHERE n < (select number from a) -1)
SELECT n FROM numbers
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 500) --example
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer. Iteration in a view?

Comment: Please let me test it and then I will mark it as right answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: should I have a table named digits with (1 .. 500) in it?

Comment: already edited away digits. "digits" is what I used it for in code when last I needed to do this.

Comment: Is Numbers a table with a field named n?

Comment: Sort of. It's a "table expression" defined right there in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of your table will be < 2048 and you are on SQL Server, this will work for you:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
   SELECT number
   FROM master..spt_values
   WHERE type = 'p'
      AND number < (SELECT value FROM yourTable)
```

Alternatively you could consider creating your own Numbers table with an appropriate size to suit your application if you require a higher limit, or are not on SQL Server that has this provided to you.  [Here](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) is a link to a blog post on the idea of having a "Numbers table" handy.